# Getting response on console but no result on page - React

Tags: reactjs, api, setstate, unirest

I'm new to react and trying to fetch some data through an API. I got response on console but i'm unable to get any result on the page. This is my Index page:

```
const url = "https://chicken-coop.p.rapidapi.com/games/"
class PcComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            games: [],            
        }
    }

    GameSearch(term) {

        const req = unirest("GET", "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" + url + term);

        req.query({
            "platform": "pc",
            "s": term
        });

        req.headers({
           
            "x-rapidapi-host": "API Name"
            "x-rapidapi-key": "API Key",
            "useQueryString": true
        });


       req.end((res) => {
            if (res.error) throw new Error(res.error);
           const games = res.body.Search;
            this.setState({ games: games}, () =>{ console.log(this.state)});

            console.log(res.body);

        });
        
    }
    render() {
       const GameSearch = _.debounce((term) => {this.GameSearch(term)},300)
        return (
            <div>
                <Search onSearchTermChange = {GameSearch} />
                {
                    this.state.games && this.state.games.map((game) => {
                    return <Game {...game}/>
   })
 }     
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

And My Code to Display the received data

```
 class Game extends Component {
     render() {
         const {title, description, image} = this.props;

         return (
             <div className="game">
                 <div className="title-description">
                     <h1 className="title">{title}</h1>
                     <h2 className="description">{description}</h2>
                 </div>
                 <div className="image">
                     <img src={image} alt="My Game Poster" />
                 </div>
             </div>
         )
     }
 }
```

I noticed that initially the state is '[]' as i defined but after the setState it gets undefined.
I attached the response i'm getting from the API. Please help me fix this :D

Comment: [Link](https://imgur.com/zqP8Lpv) Link for the API response

Comment: `res.body.Search` is not present in the response screenshot you shared. That could be the reason why you are getting `undefined` for `games`.

Comment: So any suggestions on how to fix it??

Comment: What I understood from the code is like, you are querying for a particular game in `GameSearch` method. So either  the required info from the backend is not returned as expected or you might be referring to wrong data in the response.

Comment: The issue got resolved, will post the updated code later. Thanks for the response though 